How to consume data from 3rd party API the Laravel 11 way
I'm working on project and it requires a location field with custom implementation of Google Maps autocomplete. I need it to only return [City, State] (eg. Cleveland, Ohio) or [Neighborhood, City, State] (eg. Lower East Side, New York, NY). For this I built a livewire component class which has a method that communicates with the Google Maps autocomplete web service (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete) and after some processing returns the autocomplete results to the components front end. Below is my code:
class LocationSearch extends Component {
    public $location = '';
    public $results = [];
    #[Modelable]
    public $selected = [];

    public function updatedLocation($value)
    {
        $this->reset('results');
        $response = Http::get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json', [
            'key' => env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'),
            'type' => 'political',
            'components' => 'country:us|country:ca',
            'input' => $value
        ]);
        if ($response->object()->predictions)
        {
            foreach ($response->object()->predictions as $prediction)
            {
                $name_parts = [];
                $terms_count = count($prediction->terms);
                $name_parts[] = $prediction->terms[0]->value;
                if ($terms_count > 3)
                {
                    $name_parts[] = $prediction->terms[$terms_count-3]->value;
                    $name_parts[] = $prediction->terms[$terms_count-2]->value;
                }
                else
                {
                    $name_parts[] = $prediction->terms[1]->value;
                }
                $this->results[] = [
                    'id' => $prediction->place_id,
                    'name' => implode(', ', $name_parts)
                ];
            }
        }
    }

    public function valueSelected($id,$name)
    {
        $this->location = $name;
        $this->selected = [
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name
        ];
        $this->reset('results');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.location-search');
    } }

I feel like the Google Maps logic belongs in a separate class, but I'm having trouble figuring out where. It is data so should it have its own Model? Or maybe a ServiceProvider (but that doesn't seem like it belong there)? What is the Laravel 11 way / best practice to consume data from 3rd party API's? I realize that with this small amount of logic it will be just fine living in my component class, but I'm learning and want to stick to best practices.

In Laravel, the best practice for handling third-party API integrations like Google Maps is to use a Service Class. Service classes are typically used to contain business logic or API interactions that don't naturally belong in controllers or models.
Here’s a step-by-step guide to implementing this in a maintainable way that follows Laravel best practices.
Step 1: Manually Create the Service Class
In the app directory, create a new folder called Services if it doesn’t already exist.
Then, create a new file named GoogleMapsService.php inside the app/Services directory.
mkdir -p app/Services
touch app/Services/GoogleMapsService.php

Step 2: Define the Google Maps Service Logic
Now, open GoogleMapsService.php and add the code for interacting with the Google Maps API, as discussed before. Here’s the full code:
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class GoogleMapsService
{
    protected $client;
    protected $apiKey;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->apiKey = Your API key
    }

    /**
     * Fetch autocomplete suggestions from Google Maps API.
     *
     * @param string $query
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAutocompleteSuggestions(string $query): array
    {
        if (empty($query)) {
            return [];
        }

        $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json';

        try {
            $response = $this->client->get($url, [
                'query' => [
                    'input' => $query,
                    'types' => '(cities)', // Restrict to cities
                    'key' => $this->apiKey,
                    'components' => 'country:us' // Restrict to US if needed
                ]
            ]);

            $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

            return $this->processAutocompleteResults($data['predictions'] ?? []);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return [];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process Google Maps API autocomplete results.
     *
     * @param array $predictions
     * @return array
     */
    private function processAutocompleteResults(array $predictions): array
    {
        $processedResults = [];

        foreach ($predictions as $prediction) {
            $description = $prediction['description'];
            $components = explode(', ', $description);
            $count = count($components);

            // Format: [City, State] or [Neighborhood, City, State]
            if ($count >= 2) {
                if ($count == 2) {
                    $processedResults[] = "{$components[0]}, {$components[1]}";
                } elseif ($count >= 3) {
                    $processedResults[] = "{$components[$count - 3]}, {$components[$count - 2]}, {$components[$count - 1]}";
                }
            }
        }

        return $processedResults;
    }
}

Step 3: Inject the Service into the Livewire Component
In your LocationAutocomplete Livewire component, inject and use the GoogleMapsService:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Services\GoogleMapsService;

class LocationAutocomplete extends Component
{
    
   
    protected $googleMapsService;
    public $location = '';
    public $results = [];
    #[Modelable]
    public $selected = [];

    public function mount(GoogleMapsService $googleMapsService)
    {
        $this->googleMapsService = $googleMapsService;
    }

    public function updatedQuery($value)
    {
        $this->results = $this->googleMapsService->getAutocompleteSuggestions($value);
    }

    public function valueSelected($id,$name)
    {
      $this->location = $name;
      $this->selected = [
         'id' => $id,
         'name' => $name
      ];
      $this->reset('results');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.location-search');
    }
}

Now, your Livewire component can interact with Google Maps through the GoogleMapsService, keeping it clean and maintainable. This structure is a best-practice approach in Laravel for third-party API integrations.
